# Material derivative of a vector field

Tags: vector-fields

I have this velocity field, of which I have to get the material derivative:
$$\mathbf u(x,y)=\sin(x-y)\mathbf i-\cos(x-y)\mathbf j$$
Where **i** & **j** are the vector field components.
Seems pretty straightforward:
$$\mathbf a=\mathbf u \cdot \nabla \mathbf u$$

$$\mathbf a=(\cos(x-y)-\sin(x-y))(\sin(x-y)\mathbf i-\cos(x-y)\mathbf j$$
But apparently the correct answer is:
$$\mathbf a=(\sin(x-y)+\cos(x-y))(\cos(x-y)\mathbf i+\sin(x-y)\mathbf j$$
Did I not simplify right? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

$$ \boldsymbol u \cdot \nabla \boldsymbol u = (u_1 \partial_x + u_2\partial_y)\boldsymbol{u} $$

I think you have the order wrong.